# How to query through foreign keys while only having the value in the the same row as the value used as foreign key in another column

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery

db admins, I require your help!

My experience working with databases directly using SQL is rather limited, since I've mostly been using ORMs to cover all my needs as a frontend developer, but this time I need to use SQL to
**look up a token in `tokens` table that is using an `id` column of `users` table as its foreign key *in which(in`users` table)* I only have access to the information stored in `username` column.** I'm using PostgreSQL database.

Here's a visualization:
[image: very cool picture]

Appreciate your help

Comment: Read about joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you came up with *can* work but is liable to error out should your subquery ever produce multiple results (though I'd assume unlikely) and likely is less performant than a more relational approach such as using a [`JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) like mustaccio mentioned in the comments. You should definitely read up on them, which would allow you to produce a query like such:

```
SELECT token 
FROM tokens 
INNER JOIN users
    ON tokens.id_ref = users.id
WHERE users.username = '<username>'
```

Answer (score 0):

(I leave this answer here just for the context of [J.D's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150011/j-d) solution, use JOINs)

Ok, so after fiddling with it for a bit, I found my solution:

```
SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE id_ref = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '<username>');
```